# How to open popup with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am try open a popup with jquery but popup not open i can't understand where am i wrong? please help me.

**Scripts**

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, height: 590, width: 1005 });
        });
    });
```

**css**

```
#dialog{display:none; width:800px; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:4px;}
    p{clear:both; background:blue; color:#fff; font-size:16px; padding:8px;}
```

**html**

```
<a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

..

Comment: Include `jQuery UI` library!

Comment: sorry i am not open popup with jquery ui but it's simple open with library.

Comment: how i modify my script to open the popup?

Comment: Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` to your js as Modal is not part of Jquery but Jquery-ui

Comment: You have not defined a dialog() jQuery function.  If you have, please show us the code for it.  Otherwise, you have to include jQuery UI.

Comment: Ok guys I am tailing you very frankly I am beginner in jquery and try to open a popup is this popup is related to ui technology then please tell me other way.

Comment: I search on Google but i can't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation https://jqueryui.com/dialog/. There is also a complete example on the site. Obviously you just forgot to add the jquery ui dependency.

Comment: thanks NaN but various type of method to open a popup. Like this:

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 
 //LOADING POPUP
 //Click the button event!
 $(".button").click(function(){
  //centering with css
  centerPopup();
  //load popup
  loadPopup();
 });
    
 //CLOSING POPUP
 //Click the x event!
 $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
  disablePopup();
 });
 //Click out event!
 $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
  disablePopup();
 });
 //Press Escape event!
 $(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
   disablePopup();
  }
 });

});

Comment: but this is very long and confusing way actually i wan't some short and easy method for this, not necessary i open popup for ui technique.

Comment: ok, I think my tacking of way very confusing to you and other i said to you other way look i wan't popup open like a toggle. but with overlay and with a close button.

Comment: toggle have a very short script.

Comment: Didn't get your question, but site could help you http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other posters, you need to need to include a reference to the jquery ui script. See the example below:

```css
#dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
p {
  clear: both;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#OpenDialog").click(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
          modal: true,
          height: 590,
          width: 1005
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #dialog {
      display: none;
      width: 800px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    p {
      clear: both;
      background: blue;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 8px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog
        </a>
  <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, i am not use this script i have an example to show in my question.

Comment: I understand there's no one to me or I can not explain